# Connect to Azure Analysis Services in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I've built base on several sample code, a C# script allowing to refresh a database hosted on a SSAS server but I receive an error code. 
Any idea how to fix the error?

> C# Timer trigger function exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Submission#0.Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log) in D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1\run.csx:line 14

```
#r "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DLL"
#r "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.DLL"
#r "System.Configuration"

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core;


    public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer,TraceWriter log) {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server();
                var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectStringBIDEV01"].ConnectionString;
                server.Connect(connStr);
                server.Disconnect();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function exception: {e.ToString()}");
            }

            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function finished at: {DateTime.Now}"); 
        }
```

Comment: can you edit your post and put all the exception (like stack trace) please ?

Comment: do you check if var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectStringBIDEV01"].ConnectionString; is not null ? You're edit your post without edit the exception and add the stack trace

Comment: Just to confirm whether the solution works, could you accept it as the answer if it did help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two problems `Could not load type` and `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings get null` both result from the difference of [Function Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions).

v1 functions target at Full .NET Framework and v2 is running on .NET Core env. You may have created a v2 function(by default), where Analysis Services SDK(depends on .NET Framework) is not working and ConfigurationManager is not supported.

So the solution is simple, delete existing functions and change Function runtime version to ~1(In portal, Platform features> Function app settings>) and create a v1 function.

After that, we may see some warnings about `Unable to find assembly`, just ignore them as we can connect to AnalysisServices successfully. If you meet error `On-Premise Gateway is required to access the data source. Please install a unified gateway for the server`, please follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway) to install.

Answer (score 0):

You've right, seems the connection string is null.
So I've update it by adding an Initial catalog (my connection string does not contain this variable).

So to bypass that, I've replace my 
`var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectStringBIDEV01"].ConnectionString;`

by

```
var connStr = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://northeurope.asazure.windows.net/xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx";
```

Now I receive the following message ... I suspect it's a progress but how to fix that ?

```
C# Timer trigger function exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.IdentityResolver.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Connect(String connectionString, String sessionId, ObjectExpansion expansionType)
   at Submission#0.Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log) in D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1\run.csx:line 16
```

Comment: Having the same mscorlib issue and google has not been friendly on solutions.  Anyone ever solve this particular issue with V2 and net core connect to azure analysis services?