# Connect to Azure Analysis Services in Azure Function in Runtime version 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, c#-3.0

I was trying to build a function app that can refresh Tabular analysis server tables. I have written the code referring to several documents available online. When I tried to execute the code I'm getting the "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**" error at "**var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cubeConnection"].ConnectionString;**"

In stackoverflow, I have found a similar question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327674/connect-to-azure-analysis-services-in-azure-function)) where it was asked to create a v1 function. But in my case, I can use only 3.1. Could anyone help me with this?

Below is the script which I developed.

```
#r "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DLL"
#r "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DLL"
#r "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.DLL"
#r "System.Configuration"

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;


 public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log) {
 Database db;
Model m;
try{
log.Info("started");
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server asSrv = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server();
var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cubeConnection"].ConnectionString; //failed here
log.Info("try started1");
asSrv.Connect(connStr);
log.Info("connection succeeded");
db = asSrv.Databases["DB_name"];
m = db.Model;
m.Tables["Table_name"].RequestRefresh(RefreshType.Full);
m.SaveChanges();     
asSrv.Disconnect();
}
catch (Exception e) {
log.Info($"{DateTime.Now} - {intname} - Processing function exception: {e.ToString()}");
throw;
}

}
```

Comment: Either you are missing the config file or the config file doesn't contain "cubeConnection"

Comment: I have created the "CubeConnection" in Settings-->Configuration-->Connection strings, do I have to create separate config file?

Comment: Should be App.config : see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is that `Azure Function V3` no longer uses `ConfigurationManager`.

Now you can use the following code to get the connection string:

```
var connStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cubeConnection");
```

You need to set it in `Settings-->Configuration-->Application settings`:

[image]